# can i use bottom tab screen in map function?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab

i want to use tab screen inside the map function for not repeating the same tab screen tag.. All set but the problem is this is not navigate to home to profile so any suggestion or solution? please help

```
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator()
export const navbar = [
    {
        name: 'home',
        icon: <AntDesign
            name='home'
            style={styles.iconStyle}
        />,
        component: Home
    },
    
    {
        name: 'profile',
        icon: <Avatar
            size={30}
            label={`hi`}
            color={`${colors.darkGray}`}
        />,
        component: Profile
    },
] 
function App(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
          labeled={false}
        >
          {
            navbar.map((item, index) => (
              <Tab.Screen key={index} name={item.name} component={item.component} options={{
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }: { focused: boolean, color: string }) => (
                  <>
                    {
                      item.icon
                    }
                  </>
                )
              }} />
            ))
          }
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  );
}


export default App;
```

there is a problem on above code i cant switch tabs when i use map